# how to get text using fgets, and save std::string

Tags: c++, string, io, fgets

I read txt file with fgets, and save string

and i printf_s this string, but text is broken
how can I fix this problem?

```
int main() {    
    char name[256] = "";

    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0;
    FILE *fp = 0;
    fopen_s(&fp, "a.txt", "r");
    if (fp == 0)
    {
        printf_s("can't open this file\n");
        return 0;
    }

    std::string st;
    fgets(name, 256, fp);
    st += name;
    printf_s("%s\n", name);

    fgets(name, 256, fp);
    st += name;
    printf_s("%s\n", name);

    fgets(name, 256, fp);
    st += name; 
    printf_s("%s\n", st, sizeof(st));

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

"a.txt"'s text

hello world
line 1 text
text 2 line
3 line text

and in this code, I fgets several text line in char and add this text in string named st.
can I insert all text of using fgets in string directly?

Comment: `std::string` is not `c` as far as I know. Are you mixing `c` and `c++`?

Comment: Another thing is beside that it seems a mix of C and c++, don't point your `file pointer` to `0`you have to point it to `NULL` (huge difference)

Comment: Either you're doing C, then you don't have `std::string`. Or you do C++, and then what's with all the `<stdio.h>` stuff in there? Why `fopen()` / `fgets()` / `printf()` / `fclose()`?

Comment: I learned c and c++, so I confuse to using.

Comment: So now that the question is tagged C++, I repeat _my_ question. What's with the `<stdio.h>` code strewn in? You should be using `<iostream>` and [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a bit of pointer manipulation, but first:

1. Do not mix `C++` code into your `C` program - `std::string` does not belong here.
2. Do not use `sizeof` on a `string`, there will be unexpected consequences. The length of the string is `strlen(string)`, and the size is `strlen(string)+1`.

To keep appending to `name`, you can use something like:

```
fgets(name, 256, fp);
fgets(name+strlen(name), 256-strlen(name), fp);
fgets(name+strlen(name), 256-strlen(name), fp); //Repeat (loop?)
```

This way you will aggregate the file contents to `name`. Each time you are passing a pointer that points to the previous `'\0'` character, and overwriting it while making sure you do not read in total more than 256 characters (255 and a `'\0'`).

You better make sure that:

1. `fgets` succeeds and does not return `NULL`.
2. `feof(fp)` is false.
3. You did not fill up `name` completely.